# New to H2O: How do I export a model for external use?

Tags: h2o

So I've been trying H2O for some time now. Once I have a working model, how do I export it for external use? Meaning, I want to plug in the neural-network I just got to real and live data, and get predictions. I saw there's something called POJO (which is basically Java), but the tutorials I read weren't very clear on how I plug it in to real data. So how do I do it (using H2O Flow)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mateusz Dymczyk's answer is great, though what I was looking for is a simple code snippet that presents the POJO integration. I found what I was looking for in the H2O hex.genmodel.easy [package page](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-tibshirani/8/docs-website/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/hex/genmodel/easy/package-summary.html). There's also an extensive discussion on this exact issue in Google groups, [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2ostream/N5RKoEXP_nI).

Comment: Here is a better link: 

http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/index.html

Answer (score 3):

POJO simply stands for Plain Old Java Object - the models we create are pure Java classes which have (almost) no external dependencies (only `h2o-genmodel.jar`).

Have you went through [the POJO quick start tutorial](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-docs/src/product/howto/POJO_QuickStart.md)? The tutorial is GBM binominal predictions as an example but you probably will be able to figure out how to use it with the NN.

After creating the model you download the POJO (either through Flow, R, Python or a REST call) and the `h2o-genmodel.jar` and you're all set to use it in your application. The only thing you need to do is put both the POJO (java file) and the jar on your classpath and you can use it!

@Edit:

1) To plug your POJO model into your project just copy the class to your project's source folder as you'd do with any other java class. Remember to add the appropriate `package` statement on top.

2) the `h2o-genmodel.jar` you need you can find the right version in [Maven central.](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ai.h2o/h2o-genmodel) Add it to your pom/sbt/gradle file as you'd do with any other dependency.

3) You can find a sample how to predict CSV files [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-genmodel/src/main/java/hex/genmodel/tools/PredictCsv.java) though it's not a full project. [Here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/tree/master/tutorials/hive_udf_template) is a whole webapp using a POJO model though they are using a local version of `genmodel.jar` instead of getting it from Maven central.

Comment: It's a start, but: (1) The "Use Cases" section states "The following use cases are demonstrated with code examples". Which code examples? (2) Is there a more detailed tutorial on that? For example, I'd like to use it as dependency in a Scala code built with Maven, how do I plug it in?

Comment: One more example (again, a web app, with a JS front-end): https://github.com/h2oai/app-consumer-loan

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk : The R tutorial is great. Any chance there are Scala tutorials too?

Comment: @shakedzy we don't really have that much Scala API, you can check some classes here https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/tree/master/h2o-scala but apart from that it's just the same as using the JavaAPI. We have quite a few Scala tutorials in SparklingWater https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water they are using RDDs as input but the models built are H2O so you can just swap the way you create the Frame (i.e. not from RDD but CSV for example) and use those examples